# How increase video speed into iOS without change video FPS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avasset, avassetexportsession, avcomposition

I made a video with 30FPS and 18s.
I want increase x3 the video speed and get a new video with 6s (18s/3).

I did the resolution bellow:

```
let newDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration, 1/3)
compositionVideoTrack.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                                        toDuration: newDuration)
```

The resolution is creating a new composition and scale the `CMTimeRange`.
But the video result have x3 FPS too, the result video have 90FPS.

I want a video result that has **30FPS** and **6s**, is it possible?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the answer to this question?